# use python win32gui check a button,Is there any way to Judge before check

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32, win32gui

there is a check button on windows
use python win32gui.i can find the handle and check it using PostMessage.
here is code

```
    bt=win32gui.FindWindowEx(hwnd,None,'Button','设置用户信息(&L)')
    win32gui.PostMessage(bt,win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, win32con.VK_SPACE, 0)
    win32gui.PostMessage(bt,win32con.WM_KEYUP, win32con.VK_SPACE, 0)
```

but if I accidentally run the program twice, the check button's state will be recovered

Is there any way to Judge before check,if it is checked ,the program  will do nothing.

[a check button on windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gAdr.png)

i try to find the api of the win32gui ,but Nothing found

Comment: Use [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32) to automate your UI. That's the technology that underpins [pywinauto](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)'s `uia` backend.

Comment: thank you for reply,I found the solution SendMessage(handleToControl, BM_GETCHECK, 0, 0);

Comment: [UI Automation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77094615/15511041) is a formal way. Now that you found the workaround, would you answer yourself?

Comment: That's not a solution. It just gets you one step closer to repeating the same mistake all over again: [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513). That's the issue that needs to be solved, and UI Automation is the solution.