# Get third-party application window text using WinAPI

Tags: excel, vba, winapi, screen-scraping

I'm writing a VBA script that gets the text of a local application via the WinAPI. Specifically, the WM_GETTEXT message. Here's what I got so far:

```
Option Explicit
    
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, ByVal lParam As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Public Function GetWindowTextFromWindow(ByVal windowTitle As String) As String
    Dim hWnd As LongPtr
    Dim textLength As LongPtr
    Dim buffer As String
    Dim Test As LongPtr
    Const WM_GETTEXT As LongPtr = &HD
    Const WM_GETTEXTLENGTH As LongPtr = &HE
    Const MAX_TEXT_LENGTH As LongPtr = 4096 ' Adjust as needed

    hWnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, windowTitle)
    
    If hWnd <> 0 Then
        textLength = SendMessage(hWnd, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0)
        If textLength > 0 Then
            'Range("A1") = textLength
            buffer = String(textLength, vbNullChar) ' The problem is clearly on the textLength var
            SendMessage hWnd, WM_GETTEXT, textLength + 1, ByVal buffer
            GetWindowTextFromWindow = Left(buffer, textLength)
        End If
    Else
        GetWindowTextFromWindow = "Window not found."
    End If
End Function

Sub TestGetWindowText()
    Dim windowTitle As String
    Dim windowText As String
    
    ' Set the window title of the third-party application
    windowTitle = "Novo Rede Caixa - pw3270:A - ibmrj10.corerj.caixa"
    
    windowText = GetWindowTextFromWindow(windowTitle)
    
    MsgBox windowText, vbInformation, "Window Text"
End Sub
```

The issue is that the code has a Type Mismatch (the MsgBox reads "Erro de Compilação - Tipos Incompatíveis" in Portuguese and the line that lights up is the 5th) that I have no idea how to fix.

I tried using ChatGPT and looking up some forums and tutorials, but no luck. This might be a very simple problem, given that I'm a huge newbie when it commes to WinAPI.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62420579/when-using-wm-gettext-in-sendmessage-vba-crashes and how the win32 functions are declared.

Comment: @DS_London In that question all the win32 function are declared incorrectly. In this question they are declared correctly.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you aren't using the [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32) infrastructure, or are you just not aware of the technology?

Answer (score 0):

I can't really test your code, but this is an updated version that fixes the various compile-time errors ... I've added comments in the 4 places where I have made changes.

```
Option Explicit
    
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, ByVal lParam As LongPtr) As LongPtr

Public Function GetWindowTextFromWindow(ByVal windowTitle As String) As String
    Dim hWnd As LongPtr
    Dim textLength As LongPtr
    Dim buffer As String
    Dim Test As LongPtr
    Const WM_GETTEXT As Long = &HD ' from LongPtr
    Const WM_GETTEXTLENGTH As Long = &HE ' from LongPtr
    Const MAX_TEXT_LENGTH As LongPtr = 4096 ' Adjust as needed

    hWnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, windowTitle)
    
    If hWnd <> 0 Then
        textLength = SendMessage(hWnd, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0)
        If textLength > 0 Then
            'Range("A1") = textLength
            buffer = String(CLng(textLength), vbNullChar) ' use CLng to convert LongPtr to Long
            SendMessage hWnd, WM_GETTEXT, textLength + 1, ByVal buffer
            GetWindowTextFromWindow = Left(buffer, CLng(textLength)) ' use CLng to convert LongPtr to Long
        End If
    Else
        GetWindowTextFromWindow = "Window not found."
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you! I imagined the error would be in the Long/LongPtr thingie. That said, I tried running this code and the same error appeared. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you advise exactly which line the error is on and the error number and text? Also can you confirm that your installation of Office is 64 bit not 32 bit (note this is the bitness of Office, not the bitness of Windows)?

Comment: The message is "Tipos incompatíveis", and Google tells me its a Type Mismatch Error (nbr 13.) Sorry for not specifying it earlier, and thanks for your patience!

I'm not sure how to figure out where the error is, though. Debugging doesn't seem to be working

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So when the dialog with the error appears, press the 'Debug' button and the code editor will highlight a particular line (normally in yellow) ... that is the line with the error. Can you please also check the bitness of your Office installation: in Excel (not in the VBE), select File > Account > About Excel, and near the top of the dialog you will see text including either "32-bit" or "64-bit"

Comment: Hold that ... try changing the declaration for `SendMessage` so that the final parameter is a String ie `Private Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, ByVal lParam As String) As LongPtr`

Comment: I tried hitting the Debug button both before and after running the code, and nothing. I'm not sure what's going on. On the bitness of the installation, I just checked, its 64-bits

Comment: Also, I tried changing the code to what you specified and now its having a diffferent error (progress!). Its saying "Ambiguous name detected"

Comment: "Ambiguous name detected" means you have two declarations with the same name ... check that you *replaced* the original `SendMessage` with the new one (not added another `SendMessage`)

Comment: The problem was something else, but I figured it out. Thanks! The code is no longer bugging, but it only retrieves the window title, as opposed to the whole of the window's text. At this point, do you think I should open a new question?

Comment: Yes, your code, as it stands, does only get the window title so a new question would be needed. Please click on the check/tick mark next to my answer if it helped you resolve your question.

Comment: You did! Thank you very much :3

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32) as @IInspectable said. The following c++ code uses [IUIAutomation::ElementFromPoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uiautomationclient/nf-uiautomationclient-iuiautomation-elementfrompoint).

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <UIAutomation.h>
#include <wchar.h>

IUIAutomation* g_pAutomation;

int Element(IUIAutomation* automation)
{
    // Get the element under the cursor
// Use GetPhysicalCursorPos to interact properly with
// High DPI
    POINT pt;
    GetPhysicalCursorPos(&pt);

    IUIAutomationElement* pAtMouse;
    HRESULT hr = automation->ElementFromPoint(pt, &pAtMouse);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    //ListDescendants(pAtMouse,2);

    // Get the element's name and print it
    BSTR name;
    hr = pAtMouse->get_CurrentName(&name);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        wprintf(L"Element's Name: %s \n", name);
        SysFreeString(name);

        //IUIAutomationValuePattern* pattern;
        //pAtMouse->GetCurrentPatternAs(UIA_ValuePatternId, IID_IUIAutomationValuePattern,(void**)&pattern);
        IUIAutomationLegacyIAccessiblePattern* pattern;

        //pAtMouse->GetCurrentPatternAs(UIA_LegacyIAccessiblePatternId, IID_IUIAutomationLegacyIAccessiblePattern,(void**)&pattern);
        pAtMouse->GetCurrentPatternAs(UIA_LegacyIAccessiblePatternId, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pattern));
        //TODO
        BSTR url = nullptr;
        pattern->get_CurrentValue(&url);
        DWORD state = 0;
        pattern->get_CurrentState(&state);
        BSTR elename = nullptr;
        pattern->get_CurrentName(&elename);
        DWORD role = 0;
        pattern->get_CurrentRole(&role);
        //wprintf(L"Element's ValuePattern: %s \n", url);
        SysFreeString(url);
        SysFreeString(elename);
    }
    IUIAutomationScrollPattern* pattern1;
    if (pAtMouse->GetCurrentPatternAs(UIA_ScrollPatternId, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pattern1)) == S_OK)
    {
        wprintf(L"Success! \n");
        if (pattern1)
        {
            BOOL b{};
            pattern1->get_CurrentVerticallyScrollable(&b);
            double size;
            pattern1->get_CurrentVerticalViewSize(&size);
            double p;
            pattern1->get_CurrentVerticalScrollPercent(&p);
            pattern1->SetScrollPercent(0,p+1.0);

            wprintf(L"get_CurrentVerticalViewSize:%f get_CurrentVerticalScrollPercent:%f\n", size, p);
        }
    }

    // Get the element's Control Type (in the current languange)
    // and print it
    BSTR controlType;
    hr = pAtMouse->get_CurrentLocalizedControlType(&controlType);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        wprintf(L"Element's Control Type: %s \n", controlType);
        SysFreeString(controlType);
    }

    VARIANT i;
    //pAtMouse->GetCurrentPropertyValue(UIA_ControlTypePropertyId,&i);
    pAtMouse->GetCurrentPropertyValue(UIA_NamePropertyId,&i);
    wprintf(L"Element's UIA_NamePropertyId Property Value: %s \n", i.bstrVal);
    SysFreeString(i.bstrVal);

    // Clean up our COM pointers
    pAtMouse->Release();
    return hr;
}

int main(int argc, TCHAR* argv[])
{
    // Initialize COM and create the main Automation object
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(CUIAutomation), NULL,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, __uuidof(IUIAutomation),
        (void**)&g_pAutomation);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return (hr);

    bool quit = false;
    while (!quit)
    {
        SHORT leftControlMod = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LCONTROL);
        if (leftControlMod != 0)
        {
            Element(g_pAutomation);
            Sleep(100);
        }
        quit = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE);
    }

    g_pAutomation->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'm sure this code would work great, but I can really only use VBA In this project. Sorry for not specifying this in the original post